# Mysql no results returned and I don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not getting any results for this query and I don't know why

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT website_url FROM x3_campaigns ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
    </div>
    <IFRAME SRC="<?php $battle_get['website_url'] ; ?> " WIDTH=100% HEIGHT=100%>
If you can see this, your browser doesn't 
understand IFRAME.  
</IFRAME>
```

iN SIDE

I am getting this error website_url  I have a url. So I don't know why it isn't working....

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Please post structur of your table x3_campaigns

Answer (score 3):

You should echo the $battle_get['website_url'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not `echo` your variable:

```
<IFRAME SRC="<?php echo $battle_get['website_url'] ; ?> " WIDTH=100% HEIGHT=100%>
```